# Alternate formula for $Γ(t + 1)$

Tags: derivatives, gamma-function, implicit-differentiation

I believe that:

$$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}[x^{n}] \equiv Γ(n + 1) \equiv n!$$

Would this have any application, if it has not already been discovered, which I am almost certain that it has?

Comment: This formula (with the correct value of $t$, of course), is applied in the Taylor's expansion theorem: $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2+\dots +\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{\Gamma(n+1)}x^n+\dots.$$ (Usually one uses the factorial notation $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$). Those denominators are there precisely to match the derivatives at $x=0$ of $f$ and of its Taylor polynomial.

Comment: (Therefore it is quite possible that the discoverer of this formula was precisely Taylor, that is, you. :-) )

Comment: What happens for $n$ that is non-positive integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, but it is close. The $n$th derivative of $x^n$ is $n!$. This can be proven by induction.

However $t=n-1$, thus $\Gamma(t+1)=\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$.  So you want $t=n$ instead.

So it was already known.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much.